# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:D:\login_signup\src\main\Database\login_info.db

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets, jdbc, driver

I am working on java EE. I am using intellij idea ultimate. I am trying to connect to the database. But when i try to connect using the command line in a another project it didn't give any error but when i try to do same thing in an EE app it shows me error. In this app i actually wants to read data from browser and verify it from the database. But whenever i try to connect it using EE it shows me this error.
[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKWSt.png)

[This is my formservlet code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpIbh.png)

[This is my database code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyfL9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your driver loaded? Classes are lazy loaded in java, so unless you have a code doing that for you you have to call `Class.forName("<driver class name>");` at least once to load the driver. In your case `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");`

Doing that will initialize the driver for JDBC (all JDBC drivers have static initializers).

Comment: Yes, the driver was not loaded. Now its loaded and working fine.